# Check responses code start with using regex

Tags: regex

how to detect character start with `V|N|P|D` in regex. I've try code like bellow but it not working.

ts

```
    this.respCode = 'D023';
    
    const match = this.respCode.match(/^V|\N|\P|\D(\d{3})$/);
```

Comment: Use: `^[DNPV]\d{3}$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how to detect character start with V|N|P|D in regex?

^[DNPV]

nothing else

If you put more, like \d{3} that's to follow by 3 numbers

and if you put $ at the end, it's to have no more cahracter after these numbers